# Upgrading 500 Laptops and Desktops from Windows 7 to Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

Almost all desktops have this or similar hardware:
Intel Core i3 Second Generation
RAM: 4GB RAM
Hard Drive: 350GB 
Network Card: 10/100/1000 Mbps

How do I go about upgrading 500 Desktops and Laptops from Windows 7 to Windows 8 in the most efficient way possible?

Comment: This isn't the correct site for questions like that. What you are trying to do falls more into enterprise IT. Also the question is very broad, perhaps you could at least indicate what you've already discovered.

Comment: Are you wanting to "in-place upgrade" or would you be wanting to do clean installs... knowing this can help determine what path you take. I.e. an in-place upgrade keeps the user files but a clean install wipes the drive. There are a number of "mass imaging" solutions out there that take a reference machine (Windows must be "sysprepped") and deploy it over a network to large numbers of machines simultaneously. We've experienced Microsoft's WDS and an Open Source project called FOG, to name but a couple.

Comment: Oops, meant to comment with android app but accidentally posted an answer. Here's the comment: There's a book Mastering Windows 7 Deployment that I suggest. For w8 the tools are the same: WDS, Microsoft deployment toolkit, etc. All the necessary tools are free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Windows Deployment Services(WDS). The only prerequsites are DHCP and a windows 2008 R2 server. Earlier version may work but I have not used them

Basically, you create one machine that contains ALL of the software you would like to be installed on all the other machines. Microsoft Office, windows updates, Adobe reader, etc should all be installed. Try to anticipate what every user in the company needs in terms of software. This is the template for all the PCs that will be created from this image.

Then you sysprep that single machine, and PXE boot to your WDS server. You upload the image from your 'template' machine to the WDS server, and it is now available to be installed on other machines.

Once an image is uploaded, simply PXE boot the next machine and select the Windows 8 operating system. The Windows 8 installer will load up as if you used the CD(but much quicker) and install as you normally would. You can run as many simultaneous OS installations as you network can handle. You can also have multiple 'load-outs' of pre-configured OS's, so depending which department your in, they could get a different set of software.

Benefits to this method are decreased OS installation time, and drastically decresed software installation time. I use this daily at work, and I manage 140 PCs with just myself and another guy. This also makes it easy to setup workstations for new hires, as well as scrub PCs when someone quits or the PC is just getting slow. It also brings standardization to your client PCs, so every PC has exactly the same software, which helps with troubleshooting desktop issues.

Using WDS would make this seemingly huge project much more manageable and you could easily turn it around in less than a month with just a handful of people.

Basic MS Info:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831764.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Good Guide here:
http://prajwaldesai.com/installing-and-configuring-windows-deployment-services/

I would NOT recommend any solution that involves doing direct disk clones. It would take forever, there are additional weird issues that can crop up, and this isn't 2001. There are much better ways of doing things now.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how similar your hardware is (or at least with those machines that are similar) you could install Windows 8 on one of those machines and make a complete disk backup and copy it over to all the similar machines' disk. Though I'm not really sure what you refer to as *"similar"*. I prefer Linux and disk dump (dd) for that, but alike Windows software exists, if you prefer using Windows.

But this will take an extreme amount of time!
Updating 500 machines isn't something trivial. If all those machines are seperately configured you should maybe change your setup. What about a single boot image you make available through a server to let those 500 machines boot off it? This way you would only have to update one version of Windows, though we don't know anything about the purpose of these machines and how they are currently set up.

Nevertheless this is going to be a huge PITA and there's absolutely no reason I can think of that would demand for an upgrade from Windows 7 to 8. Windows 7 is much more stable and reliable, which an enviroment like yours likely relies on. (You should at least use Windows 8.1, but seriously: Stay on Windows 7) Also, (I hope this is needless) never change a running system ;)
Anyhow, you will need to provide us with more information on your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you should use a [PXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) based technology. Forget about DVDs and USBs

On this line you can use the MS **Windows Deployment Service** (WDS) or **Microsoft Deployment Toolkit** (MDT) both based on the Windows **Automated Installation Kit** (WAIK) or Windows **Assessment and Deployment Kit** (ADK).
Be prepared for spending some time learning these tools.

Alternatively you can use [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html) (I'm related to Serva development) which automates most of the job. You just copy the the content of the install DVD to the PXE server and Serva automatically does the rest. When PXE booting a client you see a menu with the OS you want to install/upgrade. That's it.